# Zkoss - open url in browser's new tab

Tags: java, zk

I want to open url in new tab, from server side. I'm using this line:

```
Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect(url, "_blank");
```

This works perfect for Firefox but tries to open a new window in Chrome/IE. Is it possible to always open the url in new tab?

Comment: It probably depends on how the user has configured their browser (open new tab in current window or open new tab in new window)

Comment: Yes. This behavior is browser specific. zk or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Mikkel mentioned earlier this is, unfortunately, browser specific

here is an [answer](http://sourceforge.net/p/zk1/bugs/1721/) from the developers